# Android BaseAdapter with ViewHolder, not same data when scrolling

Tags: android

I try to construct a BaseAdapter with a ViewHolder, but it doesn't work on prices TextViews: sp95Price, sp98Price, gazolePrice.

**EDIT** : When I scroll the ListView, sp95, sp98, gazole prices change. They are not the same. As if there was no ViewHolder

Good to know: FuelType is a Enum, fuelStation.getPrices() is an array of FuelStationPrice (FuelStationPrice[])

```
package com.sample.my_app.adapter;

import android.location.Location;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.InjectView;
import com.sample.my_app.Application;
import com.sample.my_app.R;
import com.sample.my_app.manager.Persistence;
import com.sample.my_app.model.FuelStation;
import com.sample.my_app.model.FuelStationPrice;

public class ListStationsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
  private final LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
  private final ArrayList<FuelStation> fuelStations;
  private final Location location;

  public ListStationsAdapter(final FuelStation[] fuelStations) {
    this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(Application.getContext());
    this.location = Persistence.getInstance().getLastLocation();

    if (fuelStations != null) {
      this.fuelStations = new ArrayList<FuelStation>(Arrays.asList(fuelStations));
    } else {
      this.fuelStations = new ArrayList<FuelStation>();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return fuelStations.size();
  }

  @Override
  public FuelStation getItem(int position) {
    return fuelStations.get(position);
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
    return getItem(position).getId();
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    final FuelStation fuelStation = getItem(position);

    if (convertView != null) {
      holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    } else {
      convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.partial_line_station, parent, false);
      holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);

      if (convertView != null)
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }

    holder.name.setText(fuelStation.getName());
    holder.brand.setText(fuelStation.getBrand());
    holder.distance.setText(fuelStation.getHumanDistanceTo(location));

    for (FuelStationPrice fuelStationPrice : fuelStation.getPrices()) {
      switch (fuelStationPrice.getFuelType()) {
        case SP95:
          setPrice(holder.sp95Price, fuelStationPrice.getPrice());
          break;
        case SP98:
          setPrice(holder.sp98Price, fuelStationPrice.getPrice());
          break;
        case GAZOLE:
          setPrice(holder.gazolePrice, fuelStationPrice.getPrice());
          break;
      }
    }

    return convertView;
  }

  private static void setPrice(TextView tv, double price) {
    if (price > 0) {
      tv.setText(price + "€");
    } else {
      tv.setText("-");
    }
  }

  public static class ViewHolder {
    @InjectView(R.id.name)
    public TextView name;

    @InjectView(R.id.brand)
    public TextView brand;

    @InjectView(R.id.distance)
    public TextView distance;

    @InjectView(R.id.sp95_price)
    public TextView sp95Price;

    @InjectView(R.id.sp98_price)
    public TextView sp98Price;

    @InjectView(R.id.gazole_price)
    public TextView gazolePrice;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
      ButterKnife.inject(this, view);
    }
  }
}
```

Any one have an idea?
Many thanks before

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not very descriptive. What is it exactly that doesn't work?

Comment: When I scroll the ListView, sp95, sp98, gazole prices change. They are not the same. As if there was no ViewHolder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When views are reused, whenever you're passed in a `convertView` you need to make sure that **all** views have the correct values for this `position`.

For example, let's say a row with `fuelType == SP95` is recycled, and then reused for another in which `fuelType == SP98`. You are setting the text for the `sp98Price TextView`, **but** you didn't actually clear the `sp95Price TextView`. Hence both texts will be visible.

You could fix this particular case by clearing all three `TextViews` before assigning the correct one, i.e.

```
holder.sp95Price.setText("");
holder.sp98Price.setText("");
holder.gazolePrice.setText("");

for (FuelStationPrice fuelStationPrice : fuelStation.getPrices()) {
    switch (fuelStationPrice.getFuelType()) {
        ...
```

You could also make them invisible, or any other solution to make sure that they don't display the values from the previous time.